# I have a Google Sheet with 1000 rows, each is a different company. I would like to assign them randomly into 5 equal groups. How can I do it?

Tags: google-sheets, grouping

I have a Google Sheet with 1000 rows, each is a different company. I would like to assign them randomly into 5 equal groups. How can I do it?

I have tried to randomize a number from 1 to 5 in one column, but the problem is that wach group contains a different amount of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Also possible to achieve the same thing for any number of company names in A1:A and any number of required groups without the MAP or SEQUENCE :

```
=let(
names,tocol(A1:A,1),
groups,5,
stableRandomSortOrder,lambda(x,x)(randarray(counta(names))),
wraprows(sort(names,stableRandomSortOrder,1),groups,))
```

Answer (score 0):

***Updated formula:***

```
=let(grp,3,len,counta(A:A),Δ,(grp*ceiling(len/grp)),sort(query(tocol(map(sequence(grp),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,Δ/grp,Σ)))),"offset "&Δ-len),lambda(Σ,Σ)(randarray(len,1)),1))
```

Can you try:

```
=sort(tocol(map(sequence(5),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,200,Σ)))),lambda(Σ,Σ)(randarray(1000,1)),1)
```

[image]

Comment: **Disclaimer:** The randomized number column you achieve from this formula `will remain static` as long as it remains untouched. In other words if at a later point if you delete the formula OR cleared the formula cell & re-entered it again then you would get a  `totally fresh` randomized order. Incase you wish to avoid such a scenario what you could do is to copy this randomized order column (derived from the formula) & then `paste it back as values only` into the same or different column

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! I am not sure how it's working though. How would I be able to modify this formula for a different amount of rows and columns?

It would be great if it could work for groupings that leave a remainder, for example: 560 rows into 3 groups, leaving one group with 1 less row.

I appreciate the help

Comment: Try this updated formula: `=let(grp,3,len,counta(A:A),Δ,(grp*ceiling(len/grp)),sort(query(tocol(map(sequence(grp),lambda(Σ,wraprows(Σ,Δ/grp,Σ)))),"offset "&Δ-len),lambda(Σ,Σ)(randarray(len,1)),1))`